# Can the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 3 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$ be diagonalized over $\mathbb{Z}_5$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Im stuck on finding eigenvalues that are in the field please help.

Given matrix:
$$
A=  \left[\begin{matrix}
0 & 1\\
3 & 3
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

whose entries are from $\mathbb{Z}_5 = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$, find, if possible, matrices $P$ and $D$ over $\mathbb{Z}_5$ such that $P^{−1} AP = D$.

I have found the characteristic polynomial: $x^2-3x-3=0$
Since its over $\mathbb{Z}_5$, $x^2-3x-3=x^2+2x+2=0$.

But from there I'm not sure how to find the eigenvalues, once I get the eigenvalues that are in the field it will be easy to find the eigenvectors and create the matrix $P$.

Comment: Your field has $5$ elements, just try everyone to check which ones are roots of the polynomial. Note, however, that the field in question isn't algebraically closed, so it might even not have roots there.

Comment: Please see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) about how to format equations on this site.  In particular, I assume P-1AP=D is supposed to mean $P^{-1}AP=D$ but there is no indication of the power in what you wrote.

Comment: @user547866: It really helps readability if you format your questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards

Comment: @user547866 They don't have to be in the field and if they aren't, the matrix isn't diagonalizable over that field.

Comment: @user547866 [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/280523/55235) might interest you.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $x^2-3x-3\equiv x^2-3x+2$.

Answer (score 1):

yes over $\Bbb Z_5$  because:
$\lambda^2 -3\lambda-3=o$ at Z_5 we will have $\Delta=9+12=4+2=6$ (9~4 and 12~2 at Z_5)
so $\Delta=1$
and so $\lambda_1=\frac{3+1}{2}=2$ and $\lambda_2=\frac{3-1}{2}=1$

about:
$\lambda_1$ we have :$ ( \left[\begin{matrix}
0 & 1\\
3 &3
\end{matrix}\right]-\left[\begin{matrix}
2 & \\
0 &2
\end{matrix}\right] )\left[\begin{matrix}
x\\
y
\end{matrix}\right]=0$

$$-2x+y=0 $$ & $$( 3x+y=0 ~ -2x+y=0 ) $$ and so $$ y=2x  $$ 
is our space of eigen value of $ \lambda_1 =\{(2,4),(0,0)(1,2)\} $ => (dim =1) base={(1,2)}

about $\lambda_2$:

$ ( \left[\begin{matrix}
0 & 1\\
3 &3
\end{matrix}\right]-\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 0\\
0 &1
\end{matrix}\right] )\left[\begin{matrix}
x\\
y
\end{matrix}\right]=0$ and so $y=x$ is our answer 
 and eigenvector space of  $\lambda_2=\{(0,0)(1,1)(2,2)(3,3)(4,4)\} \implies $ $(\dim=1)$
base ={(1,1)}

**matrix at base of$ \{(1,1),(1,2)\}$ will be diagonalizable
$\left[\begin{matrix}
2 & 0\\
0 &1
\end{matrix}\right] $**