# Ways to calculate the inverse of a matrix, assuming it exists...

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm wondering - Other than by using row reduction on the augmented $[A|I]$ to get $[I|A^{-1}]$, and by reducing a matrix to a product of elementary matrices, is there any other way to determine what the inverse of a matrix is? I seem to recall something about using the adjoint of a matrix but I can't recall the details.

Comment: There's also [Cramer's rule](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448247/cramers-rule-for-inverse). It's a lot more work, but it's an alternative to Gauss Jordan.

Comment: also, there is guessing. Every so often I have a student guess an inverse to a reasonably simple $3 \times 3$ matrix, well, maybe 1 out of 200.

Comment: A related (and very fruitful) question is, what ways are there to solve $Ax = b$ without using Gaussian elimination?  Numerical linear algebra has much to say about this -- for example, QR factorization, SVD, iterative methods...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other way to calculate the inverse of a matrix $A$:

$A^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{detA}adjA$

This assumes $A$ is an invertible square matrix of course.

Another method is *Cramer's Rule*.
Cramer's Rule says the following:

> If $A$ is an invertible $n \times n$ matrix, the solution to the system $Ax=b$ of $n$ equations in the variables $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ is given by
>   $$x_1=\dfrac{detA_1}{detA}, x_2=\dfrac{detA_2}{detA},\ldots,x_n=\dfrac{detA_n}{detA}$$ where, for each $k$, $A_k$ is the matrix obtained from $A$ by replacing column $k$ by $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to calculate an inverse is by using the characteristic polynomial  of a matrix. That is, suppose $A$ matrix satisfies the polynomial equation:

$$
A^n + c_{n-1} A^{n-1} + \ldots + c_1 A + c_0 I = 0
$$

The coefficient $c_0$ must be nonzero if and only if $A$ is invertible. Then we can calculate the inverse of $A$ as a linear combination of the powers of $A$:

$$
A^{-1} = -\frac{1}{c_0}(A^{n-1} + c_{n-1}A^{n-2} + \ldots + c_2 A + c_1 I)
$$

Answer (score 0):

A "low tech" approach is to simply solve the system of equations determined by $AX=I$.  For example, when $n=2$, we have

$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x_{11} & x_{12} \\
x_{21} & x_{22} \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
=\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)$$
which is equivalent to the four equations
\begin{align}
a_{11}x_{11}+a_{12}x_{21} &=1 \\
a_{11}x_{12}+a_{12}x_{22} &=0 \\
a_{21}x_{11}+a_{22}x_{21} &=0 \\
a_{21}x_{12}+a_{22}x_{22} &=1. \\
\end{align}
Solve to find $X=A^{-1}$.