# How to find the inverse of the matrix over $\mathbb Z_5$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, inverse

How to find the inverse of the matrix over $\mathbb Z_5$

$$
\left( \begin{matrix}
 1 & 2& 0\\
 0 &2& 4 \\
 0& 0& 3\\
 \end {matrix}  \right)
$$

Comment: I know how to get inverse by adj / det operation.I am not familiar about solving this kind of questions.How should I approach by taking 9 variables matrix and solving the equations? I am confused.

Comment: In that case, compute the inverse by the adj/det operation. Where do you get stuck trying to do so?

Comment: When you compute the inverse normally, just figure out what each element is mod 5, yes?

Comment: Note that the determinant is $1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 = 6 = 1\!\!\!\! \mod\!\! 5$ so the inverse in this case is the adjoint matrix, since $1/\text{det} = 1/1 = 1 $ ( all $\!\!\!\!\mod 5$ ).

Comment: You can find several similar questions on the site (for example, have a look at the list of related question on the right). Just randomly picking two similar questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280522/how-to-find-inverse-of-a-matrix-in-bbb-z-5 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85753/i-dont-understand-why-the-inverse-is-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: One can proceed as usual by taking the given matrix $A$ and row-reducing the adjoined matrix $[\,A\,|\,\mathbb{I}\,]$. Note that the matrix is upper triangular, which makes available a very efficient method, because it implies the following about the inverse: (1) the inverse is upper triangular, and (2) the diagonal entries of the inverse are reciprocals of the diagonal entries of $A$. In other words, so the inverse has the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & a & b \\ 0 & 3 & c \\ 0 & 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then, one can simply expand the appropriate components of the equation
$A A^{-1} = 0$ to solve for the three remaining unknown components $a, b, c$.