# solving congruence equation system modulo prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I need to solve a congruence system like this:

$30f_0+26f_1+8f_2+38f_3+2f_4+40f_5+20f_6 \equiv 0 \pmod{41}$
$38f_0+2f_1+40f_2+20f_3+30f_4+26f_5+8f_6 \equiv 0 \pmod{41}$
$40f_0+20f_1+30f_2+26f_3+8f_4+38f_5+2f_6 \equiv 0 \pmod{41}$

I cannot find an algorithm to do this. I found CRT, Euclidean alg etc., but Im not sure if they can be used. How is this kind of congruences solved ? Is there any C++/Java library(like NTL), which I can use ?

Comment: Hello! Here on Math SE we would generally like to know where you got your problem from, so that we can understand what exactly you need.

Comment: It would be better to rewrite the system in another form. Enter 3 more variables or one. Well, then the system to solve elementary.

Comment: I have 7 congruences in the system, with 7 unknowns, but only this three have right side equal to 0(the others are unknown). So I need to solve these three congruences in terms of other four and substitute back to get a new system of congruences. For more detail of what I want to do, see [link](https://www.securityinnovation.com/uploads/Crypto/NTRUTech013.pdf), page 4. Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: Thankfully $41$ is a prime, so the residue classes modulo $41$ form a field. Thus you can solve this using the regular row reduction algorithm (exactly the way you were taught to solve linear systems over the reals in *Linear algebra*). [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/86367/11619) I give a walk through example modulo $29$.

Comment: Thanx @JyrkiLahtonen. That helped.