# Solve matrix equation modulo

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Let $Ax=b$, as $A|b$ is given by:

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 1 & 4\\
5 & 2 & 6\\
0 & 5 & 2
\end{array}\left|\begin{array}{c}
1\\
5\\
1
\end{array}\right.\right)$$

I want so solve the linear system: $$A\vec{x} = \vec{b} \mod{7}$$

I am quite new to modular arithmetic. I know how to row reduce $[A|b]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$. I am not sure what this question demands though.

Is it asking to obtain $rref[A|b]$ over $\mathbb{Z}_7$ get the solution?

---

Edit:
Based on the method commented below, I found rref(A|b) over $\mathbb{Z}_7$:
$$  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 &  1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
which gives the solution to $A\vec{x} = b \mod{7}$ as
$$ \vec{x} =  \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 3 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: is this a general question or do you have an equation system with numerical coefficients that you'd like to solve?

Comment: @Jneven There is a particular system: A = [3, 1, 4 \\ 5, 2, 6 \\ 0, 5, 2] and b = [1, 5, 1]^T

Comment: Clearly $\det A=12$ so $A$ is invertible.  Just compute the inverse of $A$ as usual and hence find $A^{-1}b$, or find rref of the augmented matrix, or any of the other equivalent methods.

Comment: @user10354138 thanks, you mean inv(A) over Z_7 or rref(A|b) over Z_7 like here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156813/who-to-solve-this-linear-modular-equation-system?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Computing the inverse is more work than using Gaussian elimination to convert to row echelon form. Just follow the steps in the answer to that question that you linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may solve it as if the system is over the ring $\mathbb{Z}$, and then convert it to $\mathbb{Z}_7$, but you'd probably need to preform more actions and it will be harder than by performing actions above $\mathbb{Z}_7$ from the beginning. Try to continue from here:

Thus: $ {\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 1 & 4\\
5 & 2 & 6\\
0 & 5 & 2
\end{array}\left|\begin{array}{c}
1\\
5\\
1
\end{array}\right.\right){\overset{R_{2}-4R_{1}\to R_{1}}{\Longrightarrow}}}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 1 & 4\\
-7 & -2 & -10\\
0 & 5 & 2
\end{array}\left|\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{array}\right.\right)$

and remember to convert these values to modulo 7.

Comment: $\Bbb Z$ is not a field. So you can't solve it in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @Jneven thanks, I got it: row reduce each and at each step get modulo 7. Finally I just have to read off the rref(A|b) which is the solution to the matrix equaiton.