# Finite fields: Compute the inverse of a matrix

Tags: matrices, galois-theory, finite-fields, inverse

I am working with finite fields in Python. I have a matrix containing polynomials, each polynomial is represented as an integer. For example, the polynomial `x^3 + x + 1` is represented as 11, because:

```
x^3 + x + 1 ==> (1,0,1,1) ==> (8,0,2,1) ==> 8 + 0 + 2 + 1 ==> 11
```

Given a matrix, for example:

```
6, 2, 1
7, 0, 4
1, 7, 3
```

How can I compute the inverse of a matrix in Python (or pseudo-code) ? I have already implemented the following functions (for polynomials, not matrices of polynomials): `add()`, `sub()`, `mul()`, `div()`, `inv()`

Comment: The algorithm you learned in Linear Algebra works over any field. You augment the matrix and then perform elementary row operations - arranging $1$ and $0$s to appear at the right places. Only this time the arithmetic on the entries is done using the functions you implemented yourself instead of the built-in floating point/single/double/whatever operations. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/86367/11619) I handled an example. That field was easy, because its arithmetic was just modular arithmetic. But you already have the proper substitutes for those!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen How do I arrange 1 and 0s to appear at the right places? Is there an algorithm to do that though?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Would this work if I used my arithmetic operations?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114054/matrix-inversion-without-numpy ?

Comment: Divide/multiply entire rows by constants, add multiples of a row to another, swap two rows.

Comment: Sure, with 3x3 matrices you can just use the formula with determinants and cofactors. However, for larger matrices using Gaussian elimination becomes progressively faster. It is a case of polynomial vs. exponential computational complexity.