# Find A^−1 modulo 26.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Find A^−1 modulo 26.

|4 9 15 |

|15 17 6|

|24 0 17|

i know i will have to do something like this

|4 9 15 | * | 1 0 0 |

|15 17 6| * | 0 1 0 |

|24 0 17| * | 0 0 1 |

Also if the product of the multiplication equals more then 26 i will have to mod 26 it

THE Problem is 5C)

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/328208536029102081/368955436486885376/JPEG_20171014_225708.jpg

Heres my work
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/328208536029102081/368955533199409153/Message_1508035936311.jpg

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/86367/11619) I did one modulo 29. Modulo 26 you have the extra problem that you can only find modular inverses of integers coprime to 26. So you have to be a bit more selective and/or possibly do extra row operations to get pivot entries coprime to 26. Anyway, other than such trifles (=use a modular inverse of an entry rather than the usual inverse) the algorithm you learned in linear algebra still works.

Comment: But, I don't understand what the products in the second group mean. May be you meant to have the augmented matrix there? You have taken linear algebra, haven't you?

Comment: Hey i posted pics giving links

Comment: Looks like an ok beginning to me (+1). Why did you stop there? You can easily get a $25$ in the second column. Remember that modulo $25\equiv-1\pmod{26}$ so you get a $-1$. And $-1$ is pretty much as good as $1$ for the purposes of row operations (you can later multiply a row by $-1$ because $-1$ has no common factors with $26$). You are working modulo $26$ so you can add/subtract ANY integer multiple of $26$.

Comment: Wow thanks for the info