# How to solve congruence system

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

What is the step how can I solve following system of congruences (that is one system):

> - $7x-8y≡5 \pmod {11}$
> - $2x+5y≡9 \pmod {11}$

Comment: $11$ is a prime, so integers modulo $11$ form a field. This means that you can use the same techniques as is taught over the reals in Linear Algebra. Form the matrix, and use elementary row operations. See [my old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/86367/11619) for a walk-thru example of inverting a matrix modulo $29$. Of course, you can simply use the *thinking* behind Gaussian elimination. Solve $x$ in terms of $y$ from one equation, plug it into the other etc.

Comment: But, please check out [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). Your question falls a bit short of what is expected from a question here.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the first equation with twice the second one we obtain

$$7x-8y+2(2x+5y)≡5+2(9)  \implies 11x+2y\equiv23 \implies2y\equiv 1 \mod 11$$

$$\implies 6\cdot 2y\equiv 6\cdot 1 \implies 12y\equiv6\implies y\equiv 6 \mod 11$$

Then from the second equation

$$2x+5y≡9  \implies 6\cdot 2x+6\cdot 5y \equiv 6\cdot 9 \implies12x+4\equiv 10 \implies x\equiv 6 \mod 11$$

Comment: Why there is twice second equation in first row?

Comment: @Maris It's a trick to obtain $11x\equiv 0 \mod 11$ so we only remain with $2y\equiv 1 \mod 11$

Comment: @Maris That's not a new trick. It is the same thing you would with a system over the reals: use one equatioin to eliminate one variable from the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve with gaussian elimination of matrix over $\mathbb{F}_{11}$. Noting that $-8\equiv 3\pmod{11}$ we get the following matrix:

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  2 & 5 & 9 \\
  7 & 3 & 5
\end{array}
\right] \underset{R_{2}:2R_{1}+R_{2}}{\longrightarrow}
 \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  2 & 5 & 9 \\
  0 & 2 & 1
\end{array}
\right] \underset{R_{1}:3R_{2}+R_{1}}{\longrightarrow}
 \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  2 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 2 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Now we want to divid the second by $2$, for that we need to know what is the multiplicative inverse of $2$ in $\mathbb{F}_{11}$, that is were looking for a positive integer $n\in\{n\in\mathbb{N}\mid n<11\}$ such that $2n\equiv 1 \pmod{11}$, easily enough we know it's $6$ so the solution is:
$$
 \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  1 & 0 & 6 \\
  0 & 1 & 6
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Or just $x=6,\,y=6$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig More conceptually it is $\,R_2 \leftarrow R_2 - 7/2\, R_1,\,$ where $\,-7/2\equiv 4/2\equiv 2,\,$ i.e. eliminate $x$ by scaling $R_1$ so its $x$ coef becomes $-7$ which is the negative of that of $R_2$ then add it to $R_2$ to eliminate $x.\,$ This way the row operation is not pulled out of hat - like magic. Rather, this view makes it clear that it is essentially the standard row reduction step in Gaussian elimination.

Comment: @BillDubuque  Nicely explained.

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

$5\cdot(1)+8\cdot(2)$

$$(35+16)x\equiv5\cdot5+9\cdot8\pmod{11}$$

$$-4x\equiv3-5\pmod{11}\iff2x\equiv1\iff x\equiv2^{-1}\equiv6$$

Comment: It doesn't help me to understand.

Comment: @Maris, I have eliminated $y$  See http://mathsfirst.massey.ac.nz/Algebra/SystemsofLinEq/EMeth.htm

Comment: For me there is no problem whith usual linear equation syatems. The biggest problem for me is to understand congruence... there cannot be decimal numbers etc.

Comment: @Maris, In general we understand congruence in integers and preferably non-negative. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html  . But there is also  something called http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalCongruence.html. See also : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteResidueSystem.html

Comment: $a\equiv b\bmod m\iff a=mz+b$ there's your linear problem.